# Codeigniter : How to move value from table in database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image: This is Table]

How to move the value from tes_waktu_selesai where tes_alat = 02.01.1 to tes_waktu_mulai where tes_alat = 02.01.2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use update query including the condition you mentioned

Comment: I'm a bit confuse that you want update value of  tes_waktu_selesai where  tes_alat = 02.01.1 ?

Comment: Try this UPDATE tablename SET tes_waktu_selesai='02.01.1'
WHERE tes_alat='02.01.1';

Comment: i want to input tes_waktu_mulai value with tes_waktu_selesai value from the upper row. i.e tes_waktu_mulai (02.01.2) = tes_waktu_selesai(02.01.1), tes_waktu_mulai(02.01.3) = tes_waktu_selesai(02.01.2). Do you got it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE table_name t1 SET t1.tes_waktu_mulai = t1.tes_waktu_selesai WHERE t1.tes_alat = '02.01.1';
```

If you need to interchange the values between these two let me know

Comment: i want to input tes_waktu_mulai value with tes_waktu_selesai value from the upper row. i.e tes_waktu_mulai (02.01.2) = tes_waktu_selesai(02.01.1), tes_waktu_mulai(02.01.3) = tes_waktu_selesai(02.01.2)

Comment: tes_waktu_selesai value from the upper row, is inputed to tes_waktu_mulai from the row under it. I'm sorry if my english is bad. T_T

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below

```
   INSERT INTO <totable> SELECT * FROM <from table>
```

http://phptipsntricks.com/sync-between-two-tables/

Comment: please explain to me how to use that syntax

Comment: want to to move data from user1 table to user2 where age > 18                     ` INSERT INTO user2 SELECT * FROM user1 where age =18;`  @R.P Utami Please let me know if you have any questions